# What is means by this exception in spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, stanford-nlp

> 16/03/30 23:23:20 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID
>   1, 10.208.91.144): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   edu/stanford/nlp/trees/TreebankLanguagePack   at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)     at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2499)     at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:1951)     at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getDeclaredSUID(ObjectStreamClass.java:1659)
>     at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.access$700(ObjectStreamClass.java:72)
>     at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:480)  at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:468)   at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.(ObjectStreamClass.java:468)  at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:365)  at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:602)    at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1622)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1517)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
>     at scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon.readObject(List.scala:362)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1893)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:69)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:95)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:58)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:70)   at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   edu.stanford.nlp.trees.TreebankLanguagePack   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)     ... 58 more
>
> 16/03/30 23:23:20 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.1 in stage 0.0
>   (TID 2, 10.208.91.144, PROCESS_LOCAL, 5942 bytes) 16/03/30 23:23:20
>   INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) on executor
>   10.208.91.144: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError (edu/stanford/nlp/trees/TreebankLanguagePack) [duplicate 1] 16/03/30
>   23:23:20 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 3,
>   10.208.91.144, PROCESS_LOCAL, 1435 bytes) 16/03/30 23:23:20 WARN TransportChannelHandler: Exception in connection from
>   /10.208.91.144:61788 java.io.IOException: An existing connection was
>   forcibly closed by the remote host    at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)    at
>   sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)   at
>   sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)   at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)     at
>   io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:311)
>     at
>   io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:881)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:225)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:119)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
>     at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 16/03/30 23:23:20 ERROR
>   TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 0 on 10.208.91.144: remote Rpc client
>   disassociated 16/03/30 23:23:20 INFO TaskSetManager: Re-queueing tasks
>   for 0 from TaskSet 0.0 16/03/30 23:23:20 WARN
>   ReliableDeliverySupervisor: Association with remote system
>   [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@10.208.91.144:61767] has failed, address is
>   now gated for [5000] ms. Reason is: [Disassociated]. 16/03/30 23:23:20
>   WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 2,
>   10.208.91.144): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 0 lost) 16/03/30 23:23:20 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 3,
>   10.208.91.144): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 0 lost) 16/03/30 23:23:20 INFO DAGScheduler: Executor lost: 0 (epoch 0) 16/03/30
>   23:23:20 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Trying to remove executor 0
>   from BlockManagerMaster. 16/03/30 23:23:20 INFO
>   BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Removing block manager BlockManagerId(0,
>   10.208.91.144, 61786) 16/03/30 23:23:20 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Removed 0 successfully in removeExecutor 16/03/30 23:23:20 INFO
>   AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20160330232314-0002/0 is
>   now EXITED (Command exited with code 50) 16/03/30 23:23:20 INFO
>   SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor app-20160330232314-0002/0
>   removed: Command exited with code 50 16/03/30 23:23:20 ERROR
>   SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asked to remove non-existent executor 0
>   16/03/30 23:23:20 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor added:
>   app-20160330232314-0002/1 on worker-20160330231130-10.208.91.144-61218
>   (10.208.91.144:61218) with 4 cores 16/03/30 23:23:20 INFO
>   SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID
>   app-20160330232314-0002/1 on hostPort 10.208.91.144:61218 with 4
>   cores, 512.0 MB RAM 16/03/30 23:23:20 INFO AppClient$ClientActor:
>   Executor updated: app-20160330232314-0002/1 is now RUNNING 16/03/30
>   23:23:20 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated:
>   app-20160330232314-0002/1 is now LOADING 16/03/30 23:23:23 INFO
>   SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Registered executor:
>   AkkaRpcEndpointRef(Actor[akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@10.208.91.144:61815/user/Executor#-238863041])
>   with ID 1 16/03/30 23:23:23 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.2 in
>   stage 0.0 (TID 4, 10.208.91.144, PROCESS_LOCAL, 1435 bytes) 16/03/30
>   23:23:23 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 5,
>   10.208.91.144, PROCESS_LOCAL, 5942 bytes) 16/03/30 23:23:24 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager
>   10.208.91.144:61834 with 265.4 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(1, 10.208.91.144, 61834) 16/03/30 23:23:24 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on 10.208.91.144:61834 (size: 30.4 KB,
>   free: 265.4 MB) 16/03/30 23:23:24 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.2
>   in stage 0.0 (TID 5) on executor 10.208.91.144:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
>   (edu/stanford/nlp/trees/TreebankLanguagePack) [duplicate 2] 16/03/30
>   23:23:24 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 6,
>   10.208.91.144, PROCESS_LOCAL, 5942 bytes) 16/03/30 23:23:24 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 4) on executor
>   10.208.91.144: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError (edu/stanford/nlp/trees/TreebankLanguagePack) [duplicate 3] 16/03/30
>   23:23:24 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 7,
>   10.208.91.144, PROCESS_LOCAL, 1435 bytes) 16/03/30 23:23:25 WARN TransportChannelHandler: Exception in connection from
>   /10.208.91.144:61835 java.io.IOException: An existing connection was
>   forcibly closed by the remote host    at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)    at
>   sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)   at
>   sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)   at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)     at
>   io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:311)
>     at
>   io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:881)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:225)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:119)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
>     at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 16/03/30 23:23:25 ERROR
>   TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 1 on 10.208.91.144: remote Rpc client
>   disassociated 16/03/30 23:23:25 INFO TaskSetManager: Re-queueing tasks
>   for 1 from TaskSet 0.0 16/03/30 23:23:25 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost
>   task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 7, 10.208.91.144): ExecutorLostFailure
>   (executor 1 lost) 16/03/30 23:23:25 WARN ReliableDeliverySupervisor:
>   Association with remote system
>   [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@10.208.91.144:61815] has failed, address is
>   now gated for [5000] ms. Reason is: [Disassociated]. 16/03/30 23:23:25
>   ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
>   16/03/30 23:23:25 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.3 in stage 0.0 (TID
>   6, 10.208.91.144): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 1 lost) 16/03/30
>   23:23:25 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have
>   all completed, from pool  16/03/30 23:23:25 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl:
>   Cancelling stage 0 16/03/30 23:23:25 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 0
>   (saveAsTextFile at Polarity.java:62) failed in 8.085 s 16/03/30
>   23:23:25 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 failed: saveAsTextFile at
>   Polarity.java:62, took 8.447334 s 16/03/30 23:23:25 INFO DAGScheduler:
>   Executor lost: 1 (epoch 1) org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job
>   aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most
>   recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 7, 10.208.91.144):
>   ExecutorLostFailure (executor 1 lost) Driver stacktrace:  at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1266)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1257)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1256)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>     at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1256)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
>     at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1450)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1411)
>     at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
>   Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   G:\Workspace\DSS\TextFile\part-00000 (The system cannot find the file
>   specified)    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)     at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)    at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:138)  at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:93)   at
>   java.io.FileReader.(FileReader.java:58)     at
>   com.Polarity.read(Polarity.java:94)   at
>   com.Polarity.main(Polarity.java:288) 16/03/30 23:23:25 INFO
>   BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Trying to remove executor 1 from
>   BlockManagerMaster. 16/03/30 23:23:25 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint:
>   Removing block manager BlockManagerId(1, 10.208.91.144, 61834)
>   16/03/30 23:23:25 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Removed 1 successfully in
>   removeExecutor 16/03/30 23:23:25 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor
>   updated: app-20160330232314-0002/1 is now EXITED (Command exited with
>   code 50) 16/03/30 23:23:25 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor
>   app-20160330232314-0002/1 removed: Command exited with code 50
>   16/03/30 23:23:25 ERROR SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asked to remove
>   non-existent executor 1 16/03/30 23:23:25 INFO AppClient$ClientActor:
>   Executor added: app-20160330232314-0002/2 on
>   worker-20160330231130-10.208.91.144-61218 (10.208.91.144:61218) with 4
>   cores 16/03/30 23:23:25 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Granted
>   executor ID app-20160330232314-0002/2 on hostPort 10.208.91.144:61218
>   with 4 cores, 512.0 MB RAM 16/03/30 23:23:25 INFO SparkContext:
>   Invoking stop() from shutdown hook 16/03/30 23:23:25 INFO
>   AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20160330232314-0002/2 is
>   now RUNNING 16/03/30 23:23:25 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor
>   updated: app-20160330232314-0002/2 is now LOADING 16/03/30 23:23:25
>   INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://10.208.91.144:4040
>   16/03/30 23:23:25 INFO DAGScheduler: Stopping DAGScheduler 16/03/30
>   23:23:25 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Shutting down all executors
>   16/03/30 23:23:25 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asking each
>   executor to shut down 16/03/30 23:23:25 INFO
>   MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint
>   stopped! 16/03/30 23:23:25 INFO Utils: path =
>   C:\Users\Developer\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-618a9039-a9d4-4fb2-bdc8-408d1e7f3c0e\blockmgr-4436a6d6-fca4-4190-ac2a-48c8ebd4e7db, already present as root for deletion. 16/03/30 23:23:25 INFO
>   MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared 16/03/30 23:23:25 INFO BlockManager:
>   BlockManager stopped 16/03/30 23:23:25 INFO BlockManagerMaster:
>   BlockManagerMaster stopped 16/03/30 23:23:25 INFO
>   OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint:
>   OutputCommitCoordinator stopped! 16/03/30 23:23:25 INFO
>   RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Shutting down remote
>   daemon. 16/03/30 23:23:25 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped
>   SparkContext 16/03/30 23:23:25 INFO
>   RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Remote daemon shut down;
>   proceeding with flushing remote transports. 16/03/30 23:23:25 INFO
>   Utils: Shutdown hook called 16/03/30 23:23:25 INFO Utils: Deleting
>   directory C:\Users\Developer\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-618a9039-a9d4-4fb2-bdc8-408d1e7f3c0e

this is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Fyp</groupId>
  <artifactId>DSS</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>com.Polarity</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Import Spark -->


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>  
      <groupId>jaws</groupId>  
      <artifactId>jaws</artifactId>  
      <version>1.2</version>  
      <type>jar</type>  
      <scope>system</scope>  
      <systemPath>G:/Workspace/DSS/lib/jaws-bin.jar</systemPath>  
 </dependency>  
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.3</version>
</dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
            <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
    <artifactId>stanford-parser</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
  <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
  <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
  <version>3.5.0</version>
  <classifier>models</classifier>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
     <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

</project>
```

Comment: No class def found = you don't have the right jar in your project, you need to add it to your classpath

Comment: but i add the maven dependecy for jar

Comment: then why this error occurring??

Comment: well I am no expert in maven, but edit your post to add the pom.xml

Comment: you also have a file not found exception: G:\Workspace\DSS\TextFile\part-00000

Comment: i added pom.xml yes i know (G:\Workspace\DSS\TextFile\part-00000 ) this exception but i do not understand clas notfound exception

Comment: can't find where it comes from. Maybe try other version of the standford-parser?

Answer (score 4):

The first line of the stack trace tells you what the problem is.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: edu/stanford/nlp/trees/TreebankLanguagePack at
```

If you search Google or StackOverflow for `NoClassDefFoundError`, you'll find articles describing how to fix this problem. It's not specific to Apache Spark. It's a general Java problem. In all likelihood your Java classpath is incorrectly set up---you're missing a "jar" file on the classpath, have the wrong version of a jar or have not included all the class files on the classpath.

You probably need to work out which "jar" contains the class `edu.stanford.nlp.trees.TreebankLanguagePack`. Searching Google for that class name, suggests it's the `stanford-parser.jar` that you are missing. You may be missing other jars too.

---

UPDATE: Now you've posted your maven config. I think you have specified an old version of stanford-parser.jar that does not contain the `TreebankLanguagePack` class. Try this instead:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
    <artifactId>stanford-parser</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: isn't maven suppose to do that?

Comment: Well, maybe yes. He asked what the exception means.

Comment: Looking at your maven config, it's more likely you have specified the wrong version of "stanford-parser" and the one you are using is an old version and incompatible with the other jars.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue. The error is due to missing jar files that are not attached in SparkContext.

Here is the jars that I added :

```
String jars[]={"lib/stanford-corenlp-1.3.5.jar","lib/stanford-parse-models-1.3.2.jar","lib/stanford-parser.jar","lib/stanford-parser-3.5.2-javadoc.jar","lib/stanford-postagger.jar","lib/stanford-postagger-3.5.2.jar","lib/stanford-postagger-3.5.2-javadoc.jar","lib/org.springframework.core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar"};
     SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("DSS").setMaster("spark://192.168.1.100:7077").setJars(jars);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way to solve problems like this.
Using sbt assembly (Or onejar) you can create single fat jar for your spark application.

AFAIK this is the default choice everywhere.